# Windows batch script to compare two csv files

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, compare

The first csv file contains a list of hostnames. The second csv file contains hostnames and logs. I would like to compare if the list of hostname exist in the second csv file using a batch file.

```
 for /f "skip=1" %%e in (hostname.csv) do findstr /i "%%e" logging.csv >nul&if errorlevel 1 (echo %date% %time%: Node %%e has NOT reported in the last 24 hours >> missing.txt | echo %date% %time%: Node %%e has NOT reported in the last 24 hours) else (echo %date% %time%: Node %%e reported in the last 24 hours >> found.txt)
```

I need to skip the first 2 lines in the second file (Logging.csv). How can I accomplish that?

Comment: `findstr.exe` should be the basis of your command, not `fc.exe`. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to find out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f %e in (file1) do findstr "%e" file2 >nul&if errorlevel 1 (echo %e>>missing) else (echo %e>>found)
```

As a command from the prompt. If running as a batch line, change each `%e` to `%%e`.

[untested]

---

Revision following comments

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /f "skip=1" %%e in (hostname.csv) do (
 SET "found="
 FOR /f "delims=:" %%y in ('findstr /i /n "%%e" logging.csv 2^>nul') DO IF %%y gtr 2 SET "found=%%y"
 if DEFINED found (
  echo %date% %time%: Node %%e reported in the last 24 hours >> found.txt
 ) else (
  echo %date% %time%: Node %%e has NOT reported in the last 24 hours >> missing.txt
  echo %date% %time%: Node %%e has NOT reported in the last 24 hours
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

First, I've reformatted the code.

WIth the revision, I've used the characteristic that `if defined` detects whether the variable is currently defined, using `found` as a flag.

`%%e` is set to each hostname in `hostname.csv` in turn, excepting the name in the first line (skip=1)

`found` is then "set" to *nothing*, which un-defines it.

`findstr` is then used to locate the hostname in the file. `/i` says ignore case, `/n` instructs to number the lines by preceding the `findstr` report with **originalfilelinenumber:**. `2^>nul` suppresses error messages produced by `findstr` (the caret `^` tells `cmd` that the `>` belongs to `findstr`, not `for` The `2` is "logical device 2" or the error-listing device)

The resultant report is like `1: data data %%e data data` if `%%e` is found on line 1.

The `for /f` then interprets the `findstr` report line, and assigns the data on that line, up to but not including the delimiter character (`:`) to `%%y`, then if that line number (which is the original line number from `logging.txt`) is **G**rea**t**e**r** than 2, `found` is set.

So, `found` is then either set or not, produce the appropriate data.

Comment: These seems to work great! We have the top tab we need to ignore so I have add some code to make that work as well.                                                                                                         
for /f skip^=1^ usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%e in (hostname.csv)

Comment: Top line of file1? If so, add ` "skip=1" ` after the `/f`

Comment: for /f "skip=1" %%e in (hostname.csv) do  findstr /i "%%e" logging.csv >nul&if errorlevel 1 (echo %date% %time%: Node %%e has NOT reported in the last 24 hours >> missing.txt | echo %date% %time%: Node %%e has NOT reported in the last 24 hours) else (echo %date% %time%: Node %%e reported in the last 24 hours >> found.txt) - How do i skip line in the logging.csv file?

Comment: Reformatting the code works great! I will have to read over this logic to get a better understanding but the code works.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the structure of your files, but I hope this PowerShell script can help:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\Hosts.csv) {
    if(Get-Content .\Logs.csv | Select-String $line){
        echo "The host $line exists!"
    }
    else{
        echo "The host $line doesn't exist."
    }
}
```

Where the "Hosts.csv" is the list of your hosts,
and the "Logs.csv" is a file contains the hosts and their logs in each line.

Comment: There was no [[tag:powershell]] tag, or any implied suggestion of the OP wanting a solution using it. So if you want to submit an answer using `powershell.exe` when only the [[tag:batch-file]] tag was used, please submit a solution which runs from a batch file. Be aware that a powershell script is not designed by default to run in Windows, so your answer should at least cater for that, _(when you [Edit] your answer to use `-File` over `-Command`)_.

Comment: We need to use a batch file. The first csv file contains one tab with hostnames. The second csv file contains two tabs. first tab is hostname and the second tab is log/syslog. We need to detect if all hostnames in the first csv file are in the second csv file.